# Parsec3 blocked by parsec, what ever I do

Tags: haskell, text, package-managers, parsec

using a cabal file looking like this (the relevant library part):

> build-depends:       base >=4.8 && < 4.9,   filepath >=1.4 && <1.5,  time >=1.5 && <1.6, bytestring >=0.10 && <0.11, unix >=2.7 && <2.8, cryptohash >=0.11 && <0.12, process >=1.2 && <1.3, transformers >= 0.4 && < 0.5, text >= 1.2 && <= 1.3, base16-bytestring >= 0.1.1 && < 1.1.2, utf8-string >= 1 && < 1.1, directory >=1.2 && <1.3, regex-base >= 0.9 && < 1.0, regex-pcre >= 0.94 && < 0.95, regex-base >= 0.93 && < 0.94, direct-sqlite >=2.3 && <2.4, text >=1.2 && <1.3, filemanip >=0.3 && < 0.4, **parsec3-numbers >=0.1 && < 0.2, parsec3 >=1.0 && <1.1**

I get this when doing a `cabal build` :

```
...
Couldn't match expected type ‘ParsecT
                                Text () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Double’
            with actual type ‘parsec-3.1.9:Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
                                s0 u0 m0 Double’
NB: ‘ParsecT’
      is defined in ‘Text.Parsec.Prim’ in package ‘parsec3-1.0.1.8’
    ‘parsec-3.1.9:Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT’
      is defined in ‘Text.Parsec.Prim’ in package ‘parsec-3.1.9’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: time <- floating
```

What I am trying to do is use the `floating2` parser in the `parsec3-numbers` package, but somehow I get also the interference of parsec-3.1.9.
I get the same problem if I load the failing file into ghci and with `:set -hide-package parsec` or `:set -hide-package parsec-numbers` set.

How do I make sure that I will only get parsec3 parsers? The imports I am using in the file are:

```
import Text.Parsec.Text
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Number
import qualified Data.List as DL
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO

import Database.SQLite3
import Data.Text
```

so this should work. I need the Text parsing capabilities of parsec3, that is why I went into this.

Fredrik

EDIT:

Ok, reducing this problem to a minimal form that highlights the real issue.
Using this code:

```
import Text.Parsec.Text
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Number

num:: Bool -> Parser Double
num = floating2
```

and a procedure for evaluating it that does not depend on the specific build tool used

```
> cd ~ # Move outside of any cabal package
> ghci -hide-package parsec # Parsec should now not be pulled in
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :l test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:6:7:
    Couldn't match type ‘parsec-3.1.9:Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
                           s0 u0 m0 Double’
                   with ‘ParsecT
                           Data.Text.Internal.Text () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Double’
    NB: ‘parsec-3.1.9:Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT’
          is defined in ‘Text.Parsec.Prim’ in package ‘parsec-3.1.9’
        ‘ParsecT’
          is defined in ‘Text.Parsec.Prim’ in package ‘parsec3-1.0.1.8’
    Expected type: Parser a -> Parser Double
      Actual type: Bool
                   -> parsec-3.1.9:Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s0 u0 m0 Double
    In the expression: floating2
    In an equation for ‘num’: num = floating2
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

As you can see, `parsec-3.1.9` is still pulled in, and is 'blocking' the `parsec3` definitions.

Just to provide a clean case here,  `parsec-numbers` is a package out there, and that is **not** creating the problem in this case:

```
>  ghci -hide-package parsec-numbers
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
<command line>: cannot satisfy -hide-package parsec-numbers
    (use -v for more information)
```

Comment: It is standard practice to produce a minimal working example (where here "working" means "produces the error you quoted"). For a cabal problem, that ideally includes at the very least a minimized `.cabal` file and a minimized `.hs` file. You've hinted at some of the contents of each, but there aren't enough details to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Btw - the signature for `floating2` should be `Bool -> Parser Double`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .cabal file for `parsec3-numbers` there is:

```
flag parsec3
    Description: Use parsec3
    Default: False

Library
  exposed-modules:
    Text.Parsec.Number
  if flag(parsec3)
      build-depends: parsec3
  else
      build-depends: parsec
```

So I bet you want to build `parsec3-numbers` with the `-f parsec3` option.

Comment: Fantastic! Yes, parsec3 pulls in parsec, even though I tried to block it. Recompilijg solved everything! Thanks!

Comment: Use [`-ignore-package`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#ghc-flag--ignore-package) next time. `ghci -ignore-package parsec Test.hs` results in "Failed to load interface for ‘Text.Parsec.Number’." And `ghci -ignore-package parsec -package parsec3-numbers Test.hs` results in "cannot satisfy -package parsec3-numbers: parsec3-numbers-0.1.0-5ewSm5c1kZOI1sNlSx7Ecm is unusable due to missing or recursive dependencies: parsec-3.1.11-37j7M1YEHqtEooY7BpJdri"

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I was able to satisfy all of your constraints with stack resolvers lts-5.13 and lts-6.0.

I think there is something screwed up with your package db. I would try using a cabal sandbox and/or use `stack`.

If you use `stack`, just add these to your `extra-deps:` section in the `stack.yaml` file:

```
extra-deps:
- parsec3-numbers-0.1.0
- parsec3-1.0.1.8
```

Comment: The error quoted is not about constraint solving, but about name resolution. So the knee jerk reaction of "just use stack" is not obviously sufficient.

Comment: I would still try a cabal sandbox and/or stack to make sure we have a clean build and mitigate against a corrupted pkg db. I can't see anything in the `build-depends` which directly or indirectly brings in `parsec` - do you?

Comment: `parsec3-numbers` depends on `parsec`.

Comment: Well - there you go!

Comment: That doesn't explain anything, really, which was my point all along: the question doesn't provided enough information for us to divine what's wrong yet. So we should be writing comments trying to acquire this information, not off-the-cuff answers that don't solve the problem.