# Stack linking of executable fails in one instance, completes another - why?

Tags: haskell, build, linker, ghc, haskell-stack

Sorry for asking a bit involved question, but linking an executable using stack fails inexplicably in one instance, but not in another.

This is my project:

```
$ cat stack.yaml 
extra-package-dbs: []
packages:
- umecore-hs
- fontrans-tools
extra-deps:
- parsec3-1.0.1.8
- parsec3-numbers-0.1.0
resolver: lts-5.15
flags:
      parsec3-numbers:
        parsec3: true
```

There are two executables being built here, one in each package. 
The executable section of the cabal file of the first package `umecore-hs` looks like this:

```
Executable umequery
  Main-Is:        umequery.hs
  Hs-Source-Dirs: src
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base,  parsec3, filepath,  time,  bytestring, unix, cryptohash, optparse-applicative, text, base16-bytestring, utf8-string, transformers, regex-pcre, regex-base, direct-sqlite, text , parsec3-numbers
```

and this builds fine on my OS X 10.11.5 machine:

```
$ rm -Rf .stack-work/
$ stack build umecore-hs
parsec3-1.0.1.8: configure
parsec3-1.0.1.8: build
parsec3-1.0.1.8: copy/register
parsec3-numbers-0.1.0: configure
parsec3-numbers-0.1.0: build
parsec3-numbers-0.1.0: copy/register
umecore-hs-0.0.1.0: configure
Configuring umecore-hs-0.0.1.0...
umecore-hs-0.0.1.0: build
Preprocessing library umecore-hs-0.0.1.0...
In-place registering umecore-hs-0.0.1.0...
Preprocessing executable 'umequery' for umecore-hs-0.0.1.0...
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/umequery/umequery ...
Warning: modules not listed in umecore-hs.cabal for library component (add to other-modules):
    Phonetic.Database.DataTypes
    Phonetic.Database.QueryGenerator
    Phonetic.Database.UmeQueryParser
Warning: modules not listed in umecore-hs.cabal for 'umequery' component (add to other-modules):
    Phonetic.Database.DataTypes
    Phonetic.Database.QueryGenerator
    Phonetic.Database.SegmentList
    Phonetic.Database.UmeQuery
    Phonetic.Database.UmeQueryParser
umecore-hs-0.0.1.0: copy/register
Installing library in
/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.3/umecore-hs-0.0.1.0-GFN6s0Dt0ywEgbkcE9P2if
Installing executable(s) in
/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/bin
Registering umecore-hs-0.0.1.0...
Completed 3 action(s).
$ ls -al .stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/bin
total 14352
drwxr-xr-x  3 frkkan96  staff      102 15 Jun 20:54 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 frkkan96  staff      238 15 Jun 20:54 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 frkkan96  staff  7347308 15 Jun 20:54 umequery
```

The data and time is when I ran the build command.

Ok, the corresponding section in the second package is:

```
Executable textgrid_import
  Main-Is:        textgrid_import.hs
  Hs-Source-Dirs: src
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base, filepath, directory, optparse-applicative, umecore-hs
```

But, this fails when linking the binary. (I include the verbose output, since this is what is suggested when not using the -v flag):

```
$ stack build fontrans-tools -v
Version 1.1.2, Git revision cebe10e845fed4420b6224d97dcabf20477bbd4b (3646 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.14.0
2016-06-15 21:33:04.098445: [debug] Checking for project config at: /Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/stack.yaml @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Config src/Stack/Config.hs:811:9)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.099189: [debug] Loading project config file stack.yaml @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Config src/Stack/Config.hs:829:13)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.100748: [debug] Trying to decode /Users/frkkan96/.stack/build-plan-cache/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15.cache @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Data.Binary.VersionTagged src/Data/Binary/VersionTagged.hs:55:5)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.118010: [debug] Success decoding /Users/frkkan96/.stack/build-plan-cache/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15.cache @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Data.Binary.VersionTagged src/Data/Binary/VersionTagged.hs:64:13)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.118159: [debug] Getting system compiler version @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Setup src/Stack/Setup.hs:341:17)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.118315: [debug] Run process: ghc --info @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:System.Process.Read src/System/Process/Read.hs:283:3)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.205724: [debug] Asking GHC for its version @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Setup.Installed src/Stack/Setup/Installed.hs:94:13)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.205922: [debug] Run process: ghc --numeric-version @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:System.Process.Read src/System/Process/Read.hs:283:3)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.263388: [debug] Getting Cabal package version @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.GhcPkg src/Stack/GhcPkg.hs:165:5)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.263520: [debug] Run process: ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db field --simple-output Cabal version @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:System.Process.Read src/System/Process/Read.hs:283:3)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.310570: [debug] Resolving package entries @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Setup src/Stack/Setup.hs:221:5)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.310939: [debug] Getting global package database location @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.GhcPkg src/Stack/GhcPkg.hs:48:5)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.311094: [debug] Run process: ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db list --global @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:System.Process.Read src/System/Process/Read.hs:283:3)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.391529: [debug] Run process: ghc-pkg --global --no-user-package-db dump --expand-pkgroot @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:System.Process.Read src/System/Process/Read.hs:283:3)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.448712: [debug] Ignoring package Cabal due to wanting version 1.22.8.0 instead of 1.22.5.0 @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Installed src/Stack/Build/Installed.hs:189:5)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.448902: [debug] Ignoring package haskeline due to wanting version 0.7.2.3 instead of 0.7.2.1 @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Installed src/Stack/Build/Installed.hs:189:5)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.449016: [debug] Ignoring package terminfo due to wanting version 0.4.0.2 instead of 0.4.0.1 @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Installed src/Stack/Build/Installed.hs:189:5)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.449166: [debug] Run process: ghc-pkg --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /Users/frkkan96/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:System.Process.Read src/System/Process/Read.hs:283:3)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.514425: [debug] Run process: ghc-pkg --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:System.Process.Read src/System/Process/Read.hs:283:3)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.561464: [debug] Trying to decode /Users/frkkan96/.stack/indices/Hackage/00-index.cache @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Data.Binary.VersionTagged src/Data/Binary/VersionTagged.hs:55:5)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.824920: [debug] Success decoding /Users/frkkan96/.stack/indices/Hackage/00-index.cache @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Data.Binary.VersionTagged src/Data/Binary/VersionTagged.hs:64:13)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.839361: [debug] Getting global package database location @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.GhcPkg src/Stack/GhcPkg.hs:48:5)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.839468: [debug] Run process: ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db list --global @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:System.Process.Read src/System/Process/Read.hs:283:3)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.875790: [info] fontrans-tools-0.0.1.0: configure @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:731:23)
2016-06-15 21:33:04.876185: [debug] Run process: /Users/frkkan96/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0 configure --with-ghc=/Applications/ghc-7.10.3.app/Contents/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/Applications/ghc-7.10.3.app/Contents/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/Users/frkkan96/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/pkgdb --package-db=/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/pkgdb --libdir=/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/lib --bindir=/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/bin --datadir=/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/share --libexecdir=/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/libexec --sysconfdir=/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/etc --docdir=/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/doc/fontrans-tools-0.0.1.0 --htmldir=/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/doc/fontrans-tools-0.0.1.0 --haddockdir=/Users/frkkan96/Documents/src/fonetik/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-5.15/7.10.3/doc/fontrans-tools-0.0.1.0 --dependency=base=base-4.8.2.0-cc43d8e06aa74e9c4c0132becc49ee25 --dependency=directory=directory-1.2.2.0-afaac10d677f7107a807fb2fd0eca9f4 --dependency=filepath=filepath-1.4.0.0-f97d1e4aebfd7a03be6980454fe31d6e --dependency=optparse-applicative=optparse-applicative-0.12.1.0-632ff9350432005d4b6860a3720a6388 --dependency=parsec3=parsec3-1.0.1.8-5688cfaeca7a269c6253ee69a4a21ff3 --dependency=parsec3-numbers=parsec3-numbers-0.1.0-1da0360a989926d6fcebdf3a7f1f97f7 --dependency=text=text-1.2.2.1-3d0a931105ed331bf2fb8b46dcae08ba --dependency=umecore-hs=umecore-hs-0.0.1.0-aa9f7170502bcbb7414f68ed6634ef50 --enable-tests --enable-benchmarks @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:System.Process.Read src/System/Process/Read.hs:283:3)
2016-06-15 21:33:05.517871: [info] Configuring fontrans-tools-0.0.1.0... @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:911:67)
2016-06-15 21:33:05.751514: [info] fontrans-tools-0.0.1.0: build @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:731:23)
2016-06-15 21:33:05.751664: [debug] Run process: /Users/frkkan96/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build lib:fontrans-tools exe:textgrid_import --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file" @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:System.Process.Read src/System/Process/Read.hs:283:3)
2016-06-15 21:33:05.822999: [info] Preprocessing library fontrans-tools-0.0.1.0... @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:911:67)
2016-06-15 21:33:05.924541: [info] [1 of 1] Compiling Phonetic.IPA.IPAParser ( src/Phonetic/IPA/IPAParser.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Phonetic/IPA/IPAParser.o ) @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:911:67)
2016-06-15 21:33:06.616139: [info] In-place registering fontrans-tools-0.0.1.0... @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:911:67)
2016-06-15 21:33:06.616305: [info] Preprocessing executable 'textgrid_import' for fontrans-tools-0.0.1.0... @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:911:67)
2016-06-15 21:33:06.702453: [info] [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src/textgrid_import.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/textgrid_import/textgrid_import-tmp/Main.o ) @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:911:67)
2016-06-15 21:33:07.173423: [info] Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/textgrid_import/textgrid_import ... @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:911:67)
2016-06-15 21:33:07.531282: [warn] Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:911:67)
2016-06-15 21:33:07.531443: [warn]   "_umecozuGFN6s0Dt0ywEgbkcE9P2if_PhoneticziDatabaseziDataTypes_UmeQuery_con_info", referenced from: @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:911:67)
2016-06-15 21:33:07.531618: [warn]       _ceTP_info in libHSumecore-hs-0.0.1.0-GFN6s0Dt0ywEgbkcE9P2if.a(TextgridParser.o) @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:911:67)
2016-06-15 21:33:07.548450: [warn] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:911:67)
2016-06-15 21:33:07.552040: [warn] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) @(stack_JAcs0EuAGbK5rtqRdoxQaL:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:911:67)

--  While building package fontrans-tools-0.0.1.0 using:
      /Users/frkkan96/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build lib:fontrans-tools exe:textgrid_import --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

How come the same linker on the same machine fails to link in the second case?
The one thing I can think of is that the second package loads libraries from the first package, but this should be possible, I think?

Comment: Check to see if this is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576910/parsec3-blocked-by-parsec-what-ever-i-do

Comment: How do you figure? In the `stack` setup file, I specify that the `parsec3-numbers` package should be built using `parsec3`. I clear the working directory before starting the build and the first module, which also depends on parsec3, builds fine. What could be the problem then?

Comment: Fix these warnings first: `Warning: modules not listed in umecore-hs.cabal for library component` `Warning: modules not listed in umecore-hs.cabal for 'umequery' component`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fix these warnings first: Warning: modules not listed in umecore-hs.cabal for library component Warning: modules not listed in umecore-hs.cabal for 'umequery' component – thomie Jun 25 at 11:35

I think @tomie solved it. Not sure why, but by explicitly including a duplicate of the working package specification also for building the second executable, then it started working. Not sure why the linker complained and not the compiler, but there  you go. It works.